# how to associate two test script to single test case in MTM

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests, mtm

How can I associate two Visual Studio C# test scripts with a single test case in MTM?

I have a test case like this:

[image: Test case]

and I have associated an automation script with it:

[image: Automation script associated with test case]

But I want to add one more test script to the test case. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to run other test methods from the test which you have associated with test case.